# Need to work backwards and sum the scores at an arbitrary date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to make this into a valid SQL statement?

```
SELECT 
    SUM((acc.score + SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score_amount ELSE -acc.score_amount END))) 
FROM 
    account AS acc
JOIN 
    scoring AS s ON (acc.id = s.acc_id
                 AND s.score_time >= '2018-07-01 00:00'
                 --score_type is either 'KILL_ENEMY' or 'TEAM_KILL'
                 AND SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score_amount ELSE -acc.score_amount END) + acc.current_score >= 0)
```

**Expected Output:**

> I need to sum all the scores of the accounts that are 0 or above at an
>   arbitrary date time.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

use having

```
SELECT SUM((acc.score + SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score_amount ELSE -acc.score_amount END))) FROM account AS acc
JOIN scoring AS s ON
    acc.id = s.acc_id
    and s.score_time >= '2018-07-01 00:00'       
    having sum( SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score_amount ELSE -acc.score_amount END) + acc.current_score) >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
SELECT SUM(acc.score) + SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score_amount ELSE -acc.score_amount END) FROM account AS acc
JOIN scoring AS s ON acc.id = s.acc_id
where s.score_time >= '2018-07-01 00:00' and score_type in ('KILL_ENEMY','TEAM_KILL')

having 
SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score_amount ELSE -acc.score_amount END) + sum(acc.current_score) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
SELECT  
    SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score + acc.score_amount ELSE acc.score-acc.score_amount END)
FROM account AS acc
JOIN scoring AS s ON  acc.id = s.acc_id
WHERE
    s.score_time >= '2018-07-01 00:00'
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN acc.score_type = 'KILL_ENEMY' THEN acc.score_amount ELSE -acc.score_amount END) + acc.current_score >= 0
```